# Converting string array to process array

Tags: c#

I have server that gets process list, then it converts it to comma-separated string and then sends it.

```
var processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
string sendata = string.Join(",", processlist.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray<string>());
writer.WriteLine(sendata);
writer.Flush();
```

Now on the other side I receive string and I change it to `string[]`.

```
string[] split = response.Split(',');
```

Now how can I change it from `string[]` back to `Process[]`?

Comment: Though you can instantiate new `Process` objects and give them the name what do you get from it? A `Process` object that you get from `GetProcesses` has so much more information than just a name..

Comment: Ok, so how can I send it over tcp? It's my first project with sending data through TCP

Comment: @AdrianRudyDacka : I felt you only interested in sending process names to other side of wire ? what you want to do with these names _"on the other side"_ ?

Comment: I want to show them in gridview, but i dont want only name. I want to transfer all info and show it in gridview

Comment: then why not to use splitted string only ? and display then in gridview

Comment: If you want other information, why not send *that* over TCP as well? Aside from anything else, can the receiving end even *get* the list of processes from the machine that's sending?

Comment: I want to send other info throught tcp, so on the other side i can do Process[x].ProcessName or any other command so i need to figure out how to send process[] through tcp

Comment: What you're suggesting doesn't make any sense. A `Process` object actually represents a process running on the machine. The same process isn't running on the other machine so how could knowing the name of the process possibly help? That's like me sending you the name of a person in my house and you being able to determine that persons being and weight simply from that. You need to gather all the information you need from the `Process` objects on the source machine and send it ALL.  You don't have to send `Process` objects, just objects that contain the information you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this? Note I didn't make any attempt to compile this.

You have to copy over all the properties of the Process and transmit them over the wire. On the other side, you can get out the properties and their values for display, although you will not have a real Process object.

```
public struct PropertyValue {
    public PropertyValue( string propertyName, string value) 
    { 
        this.PropertyName = propertyName;
        this.Value = this.value;
    }
    private PropertyValue( params string[] pv) => PropertyValue(pv[0], pv[1]);
    public string PropertyName {get;}
    public string Value {get;}
    override public string ToString() => this.PropertyName + ":" + this.Value;
    public static PropertyValue FromString(string pv) => return new PropertyValue( pv.Split(":"));
}
```

and then

```
public string ToString( Process process) {
    var msg = new StringBuffer();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in process.GetProperties()) {
         var propertyValue = new PropertyValue( property.Name, property.GetValue( process));
         msg.Append( ((msg.Length > 0)? ",": "") + propertyValue.ToString());
    }
    return msg.ToString();
}

public PropertyValue[] FromString( string msg) 
{
    string[] pvStrings = msg.Split(",");
    PropertyValue[] propertyValues = new PropertyValue[pvStrings.Length];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (string pvString in pvStrings) {
        propertyValues[i] = FromString( pvString);
    }
    return propertyValues;
}
```